# Type mismatch for expectMsg, required Int

Tags: scala, akka

I have the following test class for an actor:

```
class SomeActorSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("testSystem"))
  with ImplicitSender
  with WordSpecLike with MustMatchers {

  it should "check the id of a submitted job" {
    val tester = TestProbe()
    val someActorRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[SomeActor]))

    tester.send(someActorRef, SomeMessage(UUID.randomUUID))
    tester.expectMsg(SomeReply("Not running"))
  }

}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : your.package.SomeReply
[error]  required: Int
[error]     tester.expectMsg(SomeReply("Not running"))
```

Why would `expectMsg` require an `Int`?
I looked over different examples of using `expectMsg` and it was able to receive subtypes of the `Message` class.

Answer (score 2):

Strange, it loads implicit from another scope. I suggest you to write (as in your earlier question) this way:

```
import java.util.UUID

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.testkit.{TestKit, TestProbe}
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

class SomeActorSpec extends FlatSpec {

  it should "check the id of a submitted job" in new TestScope {
    val tester = TestProbe()

    tester.send(someActorRef, SomeMessage(UUID.randomUUID))
    tester.expectMsg(SomeReply("Not running"))
  }

  abstract class TestScope extends TestKit(ActorSystem("testSystem")) {
    val someActorRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[SomeActor]))
  }
}

case class SomeMessage(v: UUID)
case class SomeReply(msg: String)

class SomeActor() extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg => sender() ! SomeReply("Not running")
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `[testSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://testSystem/deadLetters] Message [my.package$StateActor$SomeReply] from Actor[akka://testSystem/user/$b#287753151] to Actor[akka://testSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
` What should I fix in the code?

Comment: I've added `with ImplicitSender` to `TestScope` but the error persists.

Comment: Hah yeah, watch out and never do that.. :)